# CircleCI display gradle test report

Tags: circleci

I'm sending the gradle test reports to `$CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS` (also tried `$CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS`) but all the html pages such as `index.html` are served as `text/plain` so it doesn't display the reports nicely.

Is there a way to tell CircleCI to display the content as html or is there another location this will work from?

My test section

```
test:
  override:
  - ./gradlew check jacocoTestReport
  post:
  - cp -R build/reports/ $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
  - mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/
  - find . -type f -regex ".*/build/test-results/.*xml" -exec cp {} $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/ \;
```